# Access 2016 VBA - Create custom collection of controls, manually specifying control's name

Tags: vba, algorithm, class, ms-access, controls

Since you can't have a vertical Control Tab in Access, I'm creating a fake one.
I wrote this piece of code to highlight (change fore color to white) the current page:

```
Private Sub updateBtnColor()
    Dim currentPageIndexSZero As Long
    Dim ctl As Control
    currentPageIndexSZero = Me.tab1
    For Each ctl In Me.Controls
        If ctl.Tag = "page" & CStr(currentPageIndexSZero) Then
            ctl.ForeColor = white
        ElseIf InStr(1, ctl.Tag, "page", vbBinaryCompare) Then
            ctl.ForeColor = black
        End If
    Next ctl
End Sub
```

Every button has got the page it's referring to as a tag, in the form of:

```
page0
page1
...
pageN
```

So the loop basically checks the current page, finds the button with the appropriate tag (assuming I named them correctly) and highlights its text.

Now this can be slow since I've got a heavy loaded form or bad practise, so I thought of creating a custom collection instead of looping through the whole Controls Collection.
I wanted to create such structure so I can loop through it, something like:

```
Enum myButtons
    button1 = Forms!myForm!button1
    button2 = Forms!myForm!button2
    button3 = Forms!myForm!button3
    button4 = Forms!myForm!button4
End Enum
```

And then:

```
Public Sub updateBtnColor()
    Dim curPageZ as Long
    Dim button as Control
    For Each button in myButtons
        With button
            If Right$(CStr(.Name, 1)) = curPageZ
                .ForeColor = 16777215 '    White
            Else                      '    No need for an additional ElseIf since I already know these are only the wanted buttons
                .ForeColor = 0        '    Black
            End If
        End With
    Next button
End Sub
```

What is the most elegant/fastest/best/proper way to create such structure or, if my idea is not that good, to create such logic?
Thanks!

Comment: You mean like this http://www.fmsinc.com/microsoftaccess/controls/components/tabs/index.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cycling thru controls works quite fast, but if you want to speedup this, use `Collection` for storing objects, not Enum. Collection can be cycled also using `For Each...`.

On form module level create a collection for your buttons:

```
Dim mcolMyButtons As New Collection
```

Then fill this collection in Open or Load events. You can use tags:

```
Dim ctl As Control
For Each ctl In Me.Controls
    If TypeOf ctl Is CommandButton Then
        If ctl.Tag Like "page*" Then
            mcolMyButtons.Add ctl
        End If
    End If
Next
```

Or just directly add buttons you want:

```
mcolMyButtons.Add Me.Button1
mcolMyButtons.Add Me.Button2
mcolMyButtons.Add Me.Button3
mcolMyButtons.Add Me.Button4
```

Then your sub:

```
Private Sub updateBtnColor()
    Dim ctl As Control
    For Each ctl In mcolMyButtons 
        If ctl.Tag = "page" & Me.tab1 Then
            ctl.ForeColor = vbWhite
        Else
            ctl.ForeColor = vbBlack
        End If
    Next ctl
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for the guidance Sergey. My only concern and the reason of this question is I don't know how to create a `Collection` of objects, so I used `Enum` as an example since they look similar. Could you show me an example on how to create a `Collection` and add a control into it? P.S. The command buttons are aligned vertically so they're at different Y's and don't overlap!

Comment: I apologize, initially I didn't understand your question correctly. My answer was wrong. I edited it, please check.

Comment: Very much thanks Sergey, this is all I was looking for on how to create a collection, it's very simple! However, since I would like to have all my custom `Collections` in a module called "basCollection", for example, is there a way to declare the Collection in a module without getting the "Invalid outside procedure" error and without using an initialization function on form Opening or Loading?

Comment: No problem, just declare collection in the standard module as Public

Comment: I defined in the standard module the following:

`Public colTabButtons As New Collection
    colTabButtons.Add Forms!Form1!Command1
    colTabButtons.Add Forms!Form1!Command2
    colTabButtons.Add Forms!Form1!Command3
    colTabButtons.Add Forms!Form1!Command4`

However, when I try to compile the code, the "Invalid outside procedure" error shows and highlights
    colTabButtons.Add `Forms`!Form1!Command53

Comment: Of course you will receive this error! You cannot perform any executions outside the procedure. Declare public function/sub and add controls inside this procedure. This procedure also can be in form module. Also this procedure should be called while the form is open, button variables will be destroyed when you close the form. So, I would recommend to leave the collection inside the form module. You can make it public and will be able to access outside the form. In this case you won't need to track if the form was closed

Comment: Thanks for the clarification Sergey, I will put the collection inside the form module to avoid complications!